# Overflow:auto and a fixed height makes dropdown text blurry in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I have a dropdown which contains multiple lines of text. I want to display all the text in a fixed height dropdown for which I use the `min-height` to set the height and in order to have a scroll if the text length is larger than the dropdown's height I use `overflow: auto`.  In Chrome/Firefox it's working fine but in Microsoft Edge the text looks blurry. An example below:

[The dropdown with overflow property added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u0xr.png)

[The dropdown without overflow property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBQAJ.png)

[Ilustration of why I need the overflow property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqjpx.png)

Initially I thought it has something to do with `popover.js` and the gpuAcceleration that CSS transform it uses when displaying the dropdown, but I fixed that and the text still looks blurry.

Edit (source code):

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
   <div class="nav-link dropdown-toggle d-inline-block" id="selectOptionThree" data-toggle="dropdown 
              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" (click)="showDescriptionOptionThree(optionThree)">
       <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pointer">Info</button>                                                                                        
   </div>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu col-lg-12" aria-labelledby="selectOptionThree" style="max-height :400px; overflow: auto;">
       <div id="optionThree"></div>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The function takes the text from a backend service and appends it to the div element with the id "optionThree".

Comment: is it possible to add also the code / demo ?

Comment: @JoeKoker Edited.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of search and tries I found that using this properties:

```
height: auto;
max-height: 400px; 
overflow: hidden;
```

fixes the problem. The problem appears only when using a fixed height dropdown with overflow in Microsoft Edge. Hopefully this will help others too.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 24 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.
I also made a test with Edge 42 and Edge 44 but not able to produce the issue. See here. https://i.postimg.cc/4yZ016jQ/99.png